# May (or June) 2010 datadump missing

Tags: support, data-dump

When I download the data dump from [May 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/creative-commons-data-dump-may-10/) my torrent client tells me it's the same file as the [Jun 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-10/) (md5s match too).

So one of them is missing. Is this just a file upload gone wrong or is one of the dumps actually missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second comment on [that page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/creative-commons-data-dump-may-10/) by Stu Thompson:

> This torrent shows up in my Transmission client as ‘ Stack Overflow Data Dump – Jun 10′. Oops.

was left on May 2nd, 2010 at 1:49 am so it was already named "June" before it even was "June".

Therefore, it seems the "May" torrent was simply misnamed.

Conveniently, Stu also has a page for every download, correctly named:

- [Stack Exchange (Stack Overflow) Data Dumps](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/)

complete with stunning mascot.

Comment: I thought that was possible, but I checked the sizes and MD5 hashes are they are the same for both torrents.

Comment: Is it possible that they became the same files when the hosting moved to ClearBits?  If so, Stu's copies preceded that (they are different sizes).