# Stack Overflow January 2011 and May 2010 data dumps

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

I am trying to access all the versions of past Stack Overflow data dumps via the torrents given on ClearBits. I am able to download all but two data dumps - `January 2011` and `May 2010`. [A prior question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105184/may-or-june-2010-datadump-missing) says that both `May 2010` and `June 2010` data dumps may be the same but it is not entirely clear. Are they the same? What is the issue with the torrent file on the `June 2011` data dump? If this would take time to fix, is there a way to get a direct download link for the same?

[image]